Optimized solution for given problem with inputs and outputs
Problem statement:

Given an unsorted array of integers, with even amount of elements,
where sum of all integers is always greater than zero, find how many
elements (at a minimum) should be moved from the beginning of array to
its end, so that sum of elements in the first half of array is not
negative.

I am unable to find the relevent problem on leetcode or geeksforgeek
Please help me the it or share the optimized solution (java) with program input and outputs
-- Sample inputs and output
new int[]{3, -1, 2, -2, 5, -3}); // Output: 0 
new int[]{1, -2, -3, 4, 5, -1}); // Output: 1 
new int[]{10, -5, -5, -5, 20, -10}); // Output: 0 
new int[]{-3, -2, 4, 5, 1, 2}); // Output: 1 
new int[]{1, 2, 3, -6, 5, 6}); // Output: 1

Solution I tried (but not giving correct answer for every input)
private static int minMoves(int[] nums) {
        System.out.println("Input nums: " + Arrays.toString(nums));
        int n = nums.length;
        int k = n / 2; // First half size
        int currentSum = 0;
        
        // Calculate the initial sum of the first half
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            currentSum += nums[i];
        }
        
        // If the initial sum is non-negative, no moves are needed
        if (currentSum >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Minimum moves required: " + 0 + " \n");
            return 0;
        }
        
        // Initialize the minMoves counter
        int minMoves = k; // Start with the worst case (move all k elements)

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            // Move nums[i] to the end
            currentSum -= nums[i];

            // Check if the new sum is non-negative
            if (currentSum >= 0) {
                minMoves = Math.min(minMoves, i + 1);
            }
        }

        // Return the minimum moves required
        System.out.println("Minimum moves required: " + minMoves + " \n");
        return minMoves;
    }
  

Can we apply any pattern to solve this problem (for example sliding window) What would be solution in that case? (I am still learning this pattern)
Thanks in advance

How do I ask and answer homework questions? We're not going to do the work for you.

Do you have any sample inputs and outputs?

The community has mixed feelings about homework questions. While some feel that students should be able to get an answer to any question they want to ask, others feel that Stack Overflow is not a place for homework questions at all. Please help me if possible

Homework questions here are fine, as long as you don't just ask us to do the work for you. Show your efforts to solve the problem yourself, and ask a specific question related to those efforts, and we'll try to help. Just posting your assignment and writing things like "share the optimized solution (java) with program inputs and outputs" is an indication that you've done absolutely nothing yourself.  Why are you taking the classes if you're not wanting to learn anything except how to copy/paste the work of other people?

I understand your point Ken, I have updated the question with my solution and inputs/outputs

See? That wasn't so hard. :-) I've retracted my close vote.

Can someone please confirm whether my solution is correct or not? Currently My solution is not giving the correct output always

Why answer for the last example is 1 rather than 0?

And should we move the whole contiguous beginning (0..p indices) or we can move separate elements? (I see the second example, but not sure...)

answer for example should be 0 bcoz sum is non-negative

If your solution is not giving the correct output, then it is not correct. Which input do you get the wrong output for?

Consider the following.
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

So your test will start by summing "0, 1, 2" you check if that is correct. Then if it isn't you "shift your window". "1, 2, 3" in your current solution you are not adding the 3 only removing the 0.
In your code, i + 1 represents how far you have "shifted" your elements.
for(int i= 0; i<n; i++){
    // Move nums[i] to the end
    currentSum -= nums[i];
    // Adds the new elements.
    currentSum += nums[(k + i)%n];
    if(currentSum >= 0){
        return i+1;
    }
}
return -1; //could not get k contiguous elements to add positive.

Some other changes:

I went from i < n because k is not the maximum number of shifts.
I used (k+i)%n because when you have shifted more then k elements you start adding the first elements back


Ok Thanks for your time and solution

In fact, it seems you're already using a sliding window approach. However, take note of the loop here.
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    // Move nums[i] to the end
    currentSum -= nums[i];

    // Check if the new sum is non-negative
    if (currentSum >= 0) {
        minMoves = Math.min(minMoves, i + 1);
    }
}

You can think of i as the current starting index of the window. As the starting index shifts forward, the ending index also increases by 1.
So, the sum of the window after it moves should be:
newSum = oldSum - oldWindow[first] + newWindow[last].
Once you understand this and properly maintain the index, you should be able to get the correct result.

Ok Thanks for your time and solution
